# How to execute action after client request sent?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an MVC action which resizes image and return it to user. I want to write resized image to disk for cache. But I don't want to delay user's response and return it before cache will be written. What is the best way to do it?

Currently, I have this code:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Resize(string fileName, int width = 0, int height = 0)
{
    var imageStream = await _fileService.GetImageAsync(fileName);
    var resizedImageStream = Resize(imageStream, width, height);

    //I want to execute this action after responce              
    async _fileService.SaveResizedAsync(fileName, resizedImageStream);

    resizedImageStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    return File(resizedImageStream, MimeUtility.GetMimeMapping("image.png"));
}
```

Comment: You could try [Background tasks with hosted services in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-2.1). In the `Resize` action, save the file to database, and use hosted service to write the file to disk as your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you need to offload it to a background thread. The simplest way to do that is with `Task.Run`, especially since you don't need a return:

```
Task.Run(() => {
    // save image data to file system
});

return File(resizedImageStream, MimeUtility.GetMimeMapping("image.png"));
```

`Task.Run` will fire off a new thread to do the work contained in the lambda, and since it's not being awaited here, the processing of your code will continue on to the `return` line.

However, this is a naive approach. Any exceptions will be swallowed, so the saving of the image may fail entirely and there's no way to recover. Since this is just for caching purposes, that may not be a problem. If it does fail, the worst case is you just end up generating it again next time. Honestly, even on something like a 5400 RPM mechanical hard drive, saving an image should be a matter of milliseconds, and even faster on a typical server class drive or SSD. You'll probably spend more ticks spinning up the thread than it would take to simply save the file directly.